# How to make bash script make a log file form from keywords

Tags: linux, bash, csv, logging

I tried to make 1 log file CSV from a complicated file with bash script, i tried but just found the keyword from the log file, please help me.

example complicated log files over ( 10k lines):

```
"$date1" "url=$a1&http=$a2&ip=$a3&from=$a4"

"$date2" "url=$b1&http=$b2&from=$a4&sip=$b5"

"$date3" "url=$c1&http=$c2&ip=$c3&UID=$c6&K-Id=c8"

"$date4" "http=$d2&ip=$d3&from=$d4&utm_id=$d7"
```

---

I found  key words and make it a file like this:

```
url
http
ip
from
sip
UID
utm_id
```

---

and I must to find how make a bash script to a file form csv like this:

```
DATE    URL   HTTP   IP   FROM   SIP   UID   utm_ID     K_id

$date1  a1     a2    a3   a4

$date2  b1     b2         b4      b5

$date3  c1     c2    c3                c6                 c8

$date4  d1     d2    d3   d4                  d7
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something to get you started. You can run it like:

```
./script_below some_log_file.log
```

The approach is basically:

```
for each line:
    initialize a new empty key-value map
    save the date into map
    for key/value pairs after date:
        put key value pair into map

    print the contents of the map
```

Here's the implementation in Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

readonly input_file="$1"

format="%s"
for i in {0..8}; do
    format="%7s$format"
done
format="$format\n"

known_keys=("date" "url" "http" "ip" "from" "sip" "UID" "utm_id" "K-Id")
printf "$format" ${known_keys[@]}

while read line; do
    unset attrs
    declare -A attrs

    vals=(${line//\"/})
    attrs['date']=${vals[0]}

    sub_vals=(${vals[1]//[=&]/ })

    set -- ${sub_vals[@]}
    while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
        attrs["$1"]="${2/$/}"
        shift
        shift
    done

    printf "$format" \
        "${attrs['date']}" "${attrs['url']}" "${attrs['http']}" "${attrs['ip']}" \
        "${attrs['from']}" "${attrs['sip']}" "${attrs['UID']}" "${attrs['utm_id']}" "${attrs['K-Id']}"


done < "$input_file"
```

This prints:

```
   date    url   http     ip   from    sip    UID utm_id   K-Id
 $date1     a1     a2     a3     a4                            

 $date2     b1     b2            a4     b5                     

 $date3     c1     c2     c3                   c6            c8

 $date4            d2     d3     d4                   d7
```

Oh also final note: while I have illustrated that this *can indeed* be done in Bash, I would recommend a full-blown, proper programming language, instead.

Comment: Dear sir , :( i'm truly a newbie, so i still can not get it from your script. :(

Comment: @chansanto no worries, i updated the post to include the printing portion.

Comment: :) very thank you for your help. I'm researching the means each line in your script to understand Sir, just because i'm newbie in bash script...Thank you again :).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workable example written in gawk, tested with the data in your question.

**log.awk**

```
/.*=.*/ { # ignore all lines without url parameters
for (i=5;i<NF;i+=2) 
    d[substr($2,0,10)][$i]++
    # if your date format is 2017-02-09T06:15:24.349847Z, change to
    # d[$2][$i]++
}

END {
for (i in d) {
    for (j in d[i]) {
        t[j]++ # find all paramters
    }
}

# print header
printf "DATE"
for (p in t) {
    printf "\t\t%s",toupper(p)
}
printf "\n"
for (i in d) {
    printf "%s",i
    for (p in t) {
        if (p in d[i]) {
            printf "\t\t%s",d[i][p]
        } else {
            printf "\t\t"
        }
    }
    printf "\n"
}
}
```

Save the content above as file `log.awk`, then in your bash shell, run as

```
$ gawk -F '["&=?]' -f log.awk little-output.log
DATE    HTTP    FROM    UTM_ID  URL K-ID    UID IP  SIP
$date1  1   1       1           1   
$date2  1   1       1               1
$date3  1           1   1   1   1   
$date4  1   1   1               1
```

The pasted result here didn't get formatted well, but result is fine in your shell output, or your can redirect the output to a file.

Comment: Thanks your help, but i still not get it. The result must be like link $A1 from website $A2 or IP$A3 :(. please help me again. and actaully, with the my log file,command about gawk or awk it's will be wrong.

Comment: this is a line in my log file, i found the keyword but dont know how to do it....  "2014-02-01T11:44:32.142372Z","http://abccom/my/?utm_source=ME+-+Definiti+Media&utm_medium=mobile&utm_term=0&utm_content=1701&utm_campaign=MY+-+No+Limits+Games&t_id=15d07b&aff_id=1437&gclid=&ip=115.164.184.31&unid=&target={target}&placement={placement}&sub1=ODUyM"

Comment: @chansanto Your link seems to broken? could you please add the correct one?

Comment: `"2017-02-01T11:44:32.142372Z","http://lp.nolimitsgamescom/my/?utm_source=ME+-+Definiti+Media&utm_medium=mobile&utm_term=0&utm_content=1701&utm_campaign=MY+-+Nes&t_id=1025b&aff_id=1437&gclid=&ip=115.164.184.31&unid=&target={target}&placement={placement}&sub1=OCw=&sub2=&sub3=&sub4=&sub5=637#ry",""`

Comment: @chansanto Sorry, I don't have enough permission to access your file. I got `403 Forbidden` error when I opened your link. Could you use another way to provide your data? in github or google drive, etc.

Comment: [link](https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/uploads-au.hipchat.com/35799/614660/AAwGhIvnOEVx41g/little-output.log) Sorry, for reply so late :( , Thanks your help, but i still not get it. The result must be like link $A1 from website $A2 or IP$A3 :(. please help me again. and actaully, with the my log file,command about gawk or awk it's will be wrong.

Comment: @chansanto OK, I have updated the answer, see if it's the result you want.